# How to make kivy urlrequests work with my android apk made in buildozer

Tags: python, android, android-studio, kivy, buildozer

Im making a moblie app which will use kivy UrlRequests, on ubuntu and macos the app works but when i make a apk with buildozer and run it on my android (OnePlus 5: android 9.0.8) via android studios the application works until the UrlRquest part where it crashes.

Ive made a test apk just to isolate and test the UrlRequest and it works on my pc/laptop and kivy launcher but not as a apk on android.

I also have the buildozer.spec and logcat file let me know if you need

Ive tried and changed the Buildozer.spec permisions and requirements to:
`android.permissions = INTERNET,ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE`

`requirements = kivy,android,openssl,pyopenssl,httplib2`

I have also tried to change https to http but still no luck

```
from kivy.clock              import Clock
from kivy.lang               import Builder
from kivy.network.urlrequest import UrlRequest
from kivy.uix.boxlayout      import BoxLayout


Builder.load_string('''
<DemoLayout>:
  orientation: "vertical"
  padding:     50
  spacing:     50

  Button:
    size_hint: (0.3, 0.3)
    pos_hint:  {"center_x": 0.5}
    text:      "Make Request"
    on_press:  app.make_request()

  Label:
    id: result_label
''')


class DemoLayout(BoxLayout):
  pass


class Demo(App):
  def build(self):
    return DemoLayout()

  def on_request_success(self, request, result):
    self.root.ids.result_label.text = str(result["data"][0]["amount"])

  def make_request(self, *args):
    UrlRequest(
      url         = "https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/GBP/spot?",
      on_error    = None,
      on_failure  = None,
      on_progress = None,
      on_redirect = None,
      on_success  = self.on_request_success,
      timeout     = 5,
    )


Demo().run()
```

I expect the output to be a value fro btc when the "Make Request" button is pressed, but the actual output is nothing

Comment: I don't know anything about Kivy and Buildozer but by default you can't run any HTTP code from the main thread in Android. Do the tools take care of that for you automatically? You'd see a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` in logcat if that's the problem.

Comment: I believe they do take acre of that automatically as there isnt a NetworkOnMainThreadException in logcat.

Comment: For Android API 21 and higher, you need to actually request the permissions (not just list them in the `buildozer.spec`). Have a look at the [documentation](https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/apis/#runtime-permissions).

Comment: @JohnAnderson okay so to my main.py i added the following from ```android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
request_permissions([Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE])``` but still no lucky, logcat keeps outputting ""Access denied finding property sys.thermal.para"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution at http://www.jiajianhudong.com/question/3324796.html 
I updated my buildozer requirments to add `certfi` and added `ca_file=certifi.where()` parameter to my UrlRequest()